# How to convert div content into an image

Tags: jquery, html

Basically I am trying to achieve an image which is saved into my local storage,so I can use it for other purpose. I have currently a div with some contents inside.

I have tried methods like canvas2Image but not succeed.Here is my code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("hello");
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.location = Image;
    canvas2Image.saveASPNG(canvas);
});
```

Any Help will help me great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("hello");
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.localStorage.canvasImage = myImage;
});
```

It should save the image as a dataURI to a localStorage's `canvasImage` variable.

Comment: Thank you Voreny, but how I can save this to a particular folder. Since I want this image to send as in email body.

Comment: @Chandan you cannot save anything on a user's device without permission. In-browser Javascript cannot do it, at least as far as I'm aware. You can only set cookies and use localStorage, they persist through reloads.

Comment: Hi Voreny, thank you so much for clearing doubts. One more thing can you help then?  I need to save an image of created highcharts as an image, and so for that I am trying to save them as a division element.  So I actually it can be done?

Comment: @Chandan I'm not sure I understand this saving as a division element. To save that image you would have to save it by yourself I guess, making a screenshot for instance and then cutting it out. Or you can paste the data from the localStorage (the `myImage` variable) as a browser url and then press Ctrl + S (at least on Windows) to save it

Comment: Hi Voreny,This error I am getting while using the above code : **Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /XYZ/function HTMLImageElement() { [native code] }**

Comment: @Chandan I have no idea what you mean.